# Filepicker.io - Picasa size limitation

Tags: filepicker.io

We're noticing some issues with Filepicker.io and the Picasa integration. It seems that large images (over ~ 2MB) aren't being processed - the POST to `www.filepicker.io/api/store/` returns `The specified bucket is not valid.` for those files. Smaller size files process just fine.

Not sure where the issue lies. The response would indicate an issue with our S3 bucket perhaps but we've been able to process large `Computer` uploads without issue. Could it be a limitation in the Picasa Web API? Any information would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Should be working now. Thanks.